# How to merge one list elements with another list elements in python?

Tags: python, list

Say I have a two lists:

```
l1 = ['a','b','c']
l2 = ['d','e','f']
```

How do I merge the elements with other list elements?

```
output: ['a_d', 'b_e', 'c_f']
```

Comment: Those don't seem to be valid Python lists. Is `a` a variable or did you mean the string literal `"a"`?

Comment: Its a string 'a'

Answer (score 3):

```
l1 = ['a','b','c']
l2 = ['d','e','f']

print([f'{x}_{y}' for x, y in zip(l1, l2)])

['a_d', 'b_e', 'c_f']
```

Comment: Or alternatively `['_'.join(i) for i in zip(l1, l2)]`

Comment: Many Thankss. It worked

Comment: WHat if I have a list1 = ['a','b','a','b'] and l2 =['e','d'] how do I insert into a new lis l3 =['a_e','b_e','a_d',b_d']

Answer (score 2):

Here is a code

```
k = 0
result = []
for i in l1: 
  result.append(i + "_" +  l2[k])
  k = k + 1


result
```

And the output is :

```
['a_d', 'b_e', 'c_f']
```

Answer (score 1):

Your can do it like this also:↓

```
l1 = ['a','b','c']
l2 = ['d','e','f']
joined_list=[]

for i in range(len(l1)):
    c=l1[i]+"_"+l2[i]
    joined_list.append(c)
print(joined_list)
```

Output:

```
['a_d', 'b_e', 'c_f']
```