# Merging two list elements into one in python?

Tags: python, list, merge

I have two lists say:

```
list1 = ['a','b','a','b']
l2 =['e','d']
```

how do I merg into a new list

```
 l3 =['a_e','b_e','a_d',b_d']
```

Comment: Could you be more descriptive in the problem? Also wb edge cases (like `len(list1) == 5`)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to merge one list elements with another list elements in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65839885/how-to-merge-one-list-elements-with-another-list-elements-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```py
list1 = ['a','b','a','b']
l2 =['e','d']

print([el1+'_'+el2 for el2 in l2 for el1 in sorted(set(list1))])
```

Output:

```
['a_e', 'b_e', 'a_d', 'b_d']
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple For loop:

```
list1 = ['a','b','a','b']
l2 =['e','d']

new_list = []
for char in list1:
    for char_2 in l2:
        item = char + '_' + char_2
        new_list.append(item)

print(new_list)
```

**Output**

```
['a_e', 'a_d', 'b_e', 'b_d', 'a_e', 'a_d', 'b_e', 'b_d']
```

---

**In case you don't want repeated Item from the first list (which is what may look from the expected list)**

Using a set will ensure not multiple items.

```
list1 = ['a','b','a','b']
l2 =['e','d']

new_list = []
for char in set(list1):
    for char_2 in l2:
        item = char + '_' + char_2
        new_list.append(item)

print(new_list)


['a_e', 'a_d', 'b_e', 'b_d']
```

### Using list comprehension

```
list1 = ['a','b','a','b']
l2 =['e','d']


new_list = [char + '_' + char_2 for char_2 in l2 for char in set(list1)]
print(new_list)
```

### Note

if for the expected Output you **Also** care about the order of the element, you can simple hack this by turning the first list in a set and the turn it back to a list as so:

```
list1 = ['a','b','a','b']
l2 =['e','d']
list1 = set(list1)
list1 = list(list1)

new_list = [char + '_' + char_2 for char_2 in l2 for char in list1]
print(new_list)
```

**Output**

```
['a_e', 'b_e', 'a_d', 'b_d']
```

### Duplicate Question

- [How to merge one list elements with another list elements in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65839885/how-to-merge-one-list-elements-with-another-list-elements-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this (here I'm assuming that `len(l2) == len(list1) / 2`):

```
l3 = [f'{list1[i]}_{l2[i//2]}' for i in range(len(list1))]
```

In case your lists are large, this approach is much more efficient than those given in other answers.